# How can I add a vertex in empty space?

Tags: vertices

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8tZ4nSTm7Tc

At 0:24 the youtuber said "then create a single vertex..." but I can't find such a command like 'add a vertex' in edit mode.

How can I create a single vertex in empty space?

Comment: You can create a plane in object mode, go to edit mode and delete 3 vertices

Comment: The shipped add-on _Add Mesh: Extra Objects_ gives you a single vert option. Ctrl-right-click to extrude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in Preferences, check "add mesh: extra objects"

[image]

then you can tap shift-a in 3d view and choose add single vert

[image]

Comment: thank you for good answer

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 2):

In edit mode, select a vertex and press shift D to duplicate, then move, or press E to extrude.

Comment: thank you for good answer

Answer (score 1):

1. Shift A to create a default cube.
2. Tab into edit mode.
3. Select one of it's vertices.
4. Press ctr + i to invert your selection.
5. Delete these vertices so you are left with just one.

You are actually done, but if you want to have the origin centered:

1. Tab out of edit mode.
2. Press Shift + S
3. Select move Origin to mesh.
4. Press Alt + G to move the object back to the center.

Comment: thank you for good answer